# Why does VB.NET Linq Lambda work one way but not the other

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am learning MVC3 and transitioning to VB.NET from C# at the same time (Fun, I know). I am running through the MvcMusicStore sample for learning MVC3. All the samples are in C# so I am converting them to VB. I came across one piece of code that I was unable to directly convert and had to change slightly to get it to work.

I have no idea why one way works and the other doesn't.

This does not work:

```
Dim albums = New List(Of Album)() From { _
    New Album() With { _
     .Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", _
     .Genre = genres.[Single](Function(g) g.Name = "Classical"), _
     .Price = 8.99D, _
     .Artist = artists.[Single](Function(a) a.Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), _
     .AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" _
    }, _
... [MORE INSTANCES]
}.ForEach(Sub(a) context.Albums.Add(a))
```

This, however, does work:

```
Dim albums = New List(Of Album)() From { _
    New Album() With { _
    .Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", _
    .Genre = genres.[Single](Function(g) g.Name = "Classical"), _
    .Price = 8.99D, _
    .Artist = artists.[Single](Function(a) a.Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), _
    .AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" _
    }, _
    ... [MORE INSTANCES]
}

albums.ForEach(Sub(a) context.Albums.Add(a))
```

The difference between the two is that the first applies the ForEach on the creation of the collection while the second applies the ForEach as a separate call.

Why does this make a difference?

EDIT: Added original C# code

The compiler does not complain here.

```
new List<Album>
{
    new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Classical"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
    ... [MORE INSTANCES]
}.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));
```

Comment: `ForEach` is not LINQ!!!  It is a method on `List<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure your problem is here:

```
Dim albums =
```

You are attempting to assign the result of the ForEach operation to the variable `albums`. `ForEach` does not return anything, so you're failing on the assignment to `albums`.

Answer (score 2):

The ForEach() method's return type is `void` and therefore does not return anything so you can not assign the result of the call to a variable.

Comment: In your fist example you are attempting to assign albums to the result of ForEach() which is your last method call. I made the same mistake when I first started using LINQ. Most LINQ methods return the IQueryable<T> object so that you can chain one method after another and pass the result along to the next method. The last method you call is ForEach(). The result of the last method is what will be assigned to albums. Since ForEach() returns void you cannot assign it to a variable.

Comment: Yet this works in the C# equivalent. Is this just a misunderstanding of mine re the differences between VB and C#?

Comment: Post the code for the C# equivalent. It will not work in either language.

Comment: Updated original question with C# code. The compiler does not complain.

Comment: Of course it doesn't... you are just calling a method, not assigning the result of the method to a variable!!! Put "var albums = " in front of your C# code... THAT is the C# equivalent of your VB.NET example that does not work.

Comment: Nice catch. That's what I get for using an automated converter rather than understanding and converting myself. Thanks again.